# Dual-Camera API for HUAWEI P9 (CAM API 2) - Caputre B/W video

Tags: android, video, camera, android-camera, huawei-mobile-services

Right now we're facing the problem, that the Huawei P9 with its B/W sensor is able to capture photos, but not videos. I wanted to write a quick and dirty solution to get the second camera working, but found out, that the phone has only "2" cameras (front/rear?!)

Does anybody know how to access the B/W sensor? I know, that the CAM API 2 has no Dual-Camera support (yet). The Huawei-Developer page suggests an API/SDK, but the button is greyed out..

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around which is already included in the APP "FreedCam". 
Huawei has some hidden parameters:

```
Regarding P9, it'sinteresting to see, that it shows only two cameras even though it has3. Any idea if the camera API 2 has the ability to use only the black and white sensor?

com.huawei.device.capabilities.availbaleDualPrimary
com.huawei.capture.metadata.dualSensorMode
```

on cam 1

```
hw-dual-primary-supported=primary,secondary,dual //primary =color, secondary = mono
hw-dual-primary-mode=primary
```

So you cannot select it as a 3rd camera.

Have a look here:
https://github.com/troop/FreeDcam/blob/42152a8e6b948dc1a05ebb99ecc6fe999c953b1e/app/src/main/java/freed/cam/featuredetector/Camera1FeatureDetectorTask.java